# Collect and Backup Photos from Multiple Photographers

Tags: backup

I have a few photographers working under me ( well, not *exactly* under me, but I say it anyway just for illustration purpose), so they shoot a lot of photos, the problem is that they all store their photos on their hard disk, and I have no way to retrieve them unless I pass them an USB and ask them to fill it with their photos.

Very labor intensive and inefficient!

Is there any other better ( more automated) ways of doing this? For the fear of losing the resolution, I don't really favor a online-synch approach, because I think all the photos uploaded to any website will suffer a resolution loss, which is the last thing I want.

Is there a better idea?

**Edit: Being artistic as they are, I can't guarantee that they all use PC and Windows; so the software must at least be able to run on Mac.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others have said Dropbox is probably the best option but you will have to pay for the kind of amount of data you likely to need to use. Unless you just have them put in a temporary copy that you move out of the folder.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to have a look at [Microsoft Sync toy using](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) UNC shares (if on same network)

If spread out across the internet, take a look at [Microsoft Live Mesh](http://www.mesh.com) and [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com)

Comment: great tools, I was always searching for something like that!

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use online-sync approach without resolution loss. Your are exchanging raw files, not modified files.

One service that you can use is, for example, [Live Mesh](http://www.mesh.com/) or DropBox. You can use them with Microsoft Systems or Mac Os.

Comment: Live Mesh and DropBox work on Windows an Mac OsX

Answer (score 1):

Try sharing a [private Picasa web album with sync to web enabled](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=93773).  The files are not compressed.

Answer (score 0):

DropBox and LiveMesh would be great. But I think they both have some pretty small (relatively for raw photos) limits on total size you're allowed to have on the cloud.

Perhaps consider creating an ftp server that can be set up on other computers as an accessible ftp folder. I know Windows can do this, but i'm not sure about Macs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new player in this field that might help you: [cubby](http://cubby.com)

Cubby allows you to share folders of any size by doing a computer to computer sync without syncing to the cloud. Create a logmein.com account and then download cubby from cubby.com/download and you should be able to get it working today rather than having to wait through the invite process.